# Add HTTP server to Electron application

Tags: node.js, http, electron

I was wondering how an HTTP server can be added to an Electron desktop application.  The server should start when the app starts and serve files, which are stored locally.  If a file from inside a zip archive is requested like so `/myfolder/myarchive.zip/picture.jpg` the server should extract it and serve it.  I'm mostly interested in how to bundle the server.

Comment: did you tried express?

Comment: How does Express allow bundling a Node.js server with an Electron App?  I understand that Express is a framework which can be used after a Node.js server has already been set up.

Comment: express wraps node http methods and in overall is easier to use, you can use either

Comment: I would like the Node.js server to start whenever the user runs the Electron desktop app by clicking its .exe file.  It does not appear that Express helps to accomplish this.

Comment: actually you can, i use it to print some documents, just add the script of start on the main of electron and obviously its dependency and run perfectly

Comment: Thanks I'll take a look.  It appears that there are some examples of express+electron integration out there.

Answer (score 1):

In `main.js` add

```
const myscript = require('./path/to/nodeJS_server_script.js');
```

The same works for a script, which uses Express.  (Express obviously needs to be installed in this case)